# FFMPEG EXR to TIFF works, TIFF TO JPG, but not EXR to JPG

Tags: ffmpeg, images, conversion

I try to batch-convert **EXR** Images to **JPG** Images. Converting **EXR** to **JPG** **doesn't work**, i get a corrupt error when trying opening the file.

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i C:/test.exr C:/outs.jpg
```

But Converting **EXR to TIFF works** fine

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i C:/test.exr C:/outs.tiff
```

And converting **TIFF to JPG works** as well:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y -i C:/test.tiff C:/outs.jpg
```

I don't want to double convert a file to get to my end-result..is there a solution for that problem?

**Output of first command:**

```
ffmpeg version N-51683-g9dc88ac Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Apr  8 2013 21:24:37 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 25.100 / 52. 25.100
  libavcodec     55.  2.100 / 55.  2.100
  libavformat    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
  libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
  libavfilter     3. 49.101 /  3. 49.101
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[image2 @ 00000000045f6480] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, image2, from 'V:\040_Footage\001_Elements_out\2K_EXR\Event_Version1_0001_0064\VFX_Plates_Cam_9624_CineF14.1000.exr':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: exr, rgb48le, 2048x1152 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Output #0, image2, to 'V:\040_Footage\001_Elements_out\2K_EXR\Event_Version 1_0001_0064\tiff\VFX_Plates_Cam_9624_CineF14.1000.jpg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.1.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p, 2048x1152 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (exr -> mjpeg)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=N/A
video:90kB audio:0kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.023799%
```

Example File: 
http://we.tl/BIWAGR506u

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output from your first command.

Comment: Do you have any new Idea?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input file so I can attempt to duplicate any issues? Does it make a difference if you add `-vframes 1` as an output option? Your `ffmpeg` version is dated; can you try a recent one?

Comment: i've add an example file, -vframes didn't work.